# Unsorted array, headers_list(), make keys for array?

Tags: php, arrays, http-headers

As you know, the `headers_list()`-PHP-function returns an array like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8
    [1] => key: value
    [2] => key2: value2
)
```

In general (or with this example), how can you build a new array using the "key" in the arrays value? For example, the array above becomes:

```
Array
(
    ['Content-type'] => text/html; charset=utf-8
    ['key'] => value
    ['key2'] => value2
)
```

This is probably really basic, but I am still a beginner :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work:

```
$headers = header_list();
foreach($headers as $header){
    // split each header by ':' and assign them to $key and $value
    list($key, $value) = explode(':', $header, 2); // limit the explode to 2 items. 
    // add trimed variables to the new array
    $new_headers[trim($key)] = trim($value);
}
```

Probably trim for `$key` is not really important, but for value it really is, because you will remove the space after the ':'.

Comment: you beat me by, like, 2 seconds!

Comment: the most important is not the speed, but the quality :)

Comment: Saving the call to trim() and just explode by ": " would be faster. Slightly.

Comment: @JMC Creative: I agree. That was just in case.

Comment: It's okey, I can predict the value of the headers I need anyway (regarding the "trim"-statements). Thanks :)

Comment: trim on the $key is unnecessary, but a `strtolower` is highly advised. Header "keys" are treated as case insensitive but array keys are not.

Answer (score 2):

You should use this function [apache_response_headers](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.apache-response-headers.php) instead , is return the header in array ...

however, the function name expose it works for apache only

updated: PHP need to compile with `--with-apxs2`

Comment: I have an Apache-server, but I'm not sure if my client has that, so I'll accept the other answer that sorts the header-fields because that's what I asked for, but I will probably end up using your solution anyways :) (I hate that the comment is posted when pressing enter…)

Comment: It will work anyway, you don't need any additional functionality on the client side

Comment: Didn't work for me. `Fatal error: Call to undefined function apache_response_headers()`

Comment: (@s3v3n: I meant that the server I am developing for may not be Apache)

Comment: ops...this function require php 4.3++, and apache, and php compiled with `--with-apxs2` , discard using this ...

Comment: Yes, you're right. As ajreal pointed, this function doesn't not exist on lighttpd. So use `header_list()` :)

Comment: One more trick you should do, is to call `ob_end_flush()` before calling `apache_response_headers()`, otherwise it can not return all the headers.

Answer (score 1):

```
foreach($headers as $v) {
    list($name,$val) = explode(': ',$v);
    $newArray[$name] = $val;
}

// $newArray is your requested array.
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$headers = header_list();
$keyed_headers = array();
foreach ($headers as $header) {
    $break = explode(': ', $header, 2);
    $keyed_headers[$break[0]] = $break[1];
}
```

**UPDATE**

On a whim, I decided that it would be **MoarAwesome<sup>TM</sup>** to solve this problem using a class.  This was the result:

```
// definition
class HeaderArray extends ArrayObject {
    static function init() {
        return new self(header_list());
    }
    public function get_assoc() {
        $result = new self();
        foreach ($this as $v) {
            $b = explode(': ', $v, 2);
            $result[$b[0]] = $b[1];
        }
        return $result;
    }
}

// implementation
$headers = HeaderArray::init()->get_assoc();
```

Answer (score 1):

The following function is be able to handle multiple header fields with the same field name and combines them [as stipulated by the specification](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec4.html#sec4.2):

> Multiple message-header fields with the same field-name MAY be present in a message if and only if the entire field-value for that header field is defined as a comma-separated list [i.e., #(values)]. It MUST be possible to combine the multiple header fields into one "field-name: field-value" pair, without changing the semantics of the message, by appending each subsequent field-value to the first, each separated by a comma.

```
function getHeaderFields() {
    $fields = array();
    $index = array();
    foreach (headers_list() as $field) {
        list($name, $value) = explode(':', $field, 2);
        $name = trim($name);
        if (isset($index[strtolower($name)])) {
            $name = $index[strtolower($name)];
        } else {
            $index[strtolower($name)] = $name;
        }
        if (isset($fields[$name])) {
            $fields[$name] .= ', '.trim($value);
        } else {
            $fields[$name] = trim($value);
        }
    }
    return $fields;
}
```

This works in opposite to [`apache_response_headers`](http://php.net/apache_response_headers) or the other mentioned solutions:

```
setcookie('foo', 'bar');
setcookie('bar', 'quux');
$headers = getHeaderFields();
var_dump($headers['Set-Cookie']);      // string(17) "foo=bar, bar=quux"
$headers = apache_response_headers();
var_dump($headers['Set-Cookie']);      //  string(8) "bar=quux"
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this is better: you should reimplode the remainder in case there was a ':' in a value

```
$hList = headers_list();

    foreach ($hList as $header) {
        $header = explode(":", $header);
        $headers[ array_shift($header) ] = trim( implode(":", $header) );
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

My Solution:

```
/**
 * Get HTTP Response Headers
 *
 * @param  null|string  $key
 *
 * @return array|mixed|string|null
 */
function get_response_headers( $key = null ) {

    $headers = [];

    if ( ! empty( $key ) ) {
        $key = strtolower( $key );
    }

    foreach ( headers_list() as $header ) {
        $header = explode( ":", $header );

        $index = trim( array_shift( $header ) );
        $value = trim( implode( ":", $header ) );

        if (
            ! empty( $key ) &&
            $key === strtolower( $index )
        ) {
            return $value;
        }

        $headers[ $index ] = $value;
    }

    if ( ! empty( $key ) ) {
        return null;
    }

    return $headers;
}
```