# Check already set response headers in PHP (before they are sent)

Tags: php

I am trying to find a way to **check the headers that have already been set by PHP**. Example:

```
<?php
header('Location: https://www.google.fr');

// Later in the code
$location = get_header('Location');
```

Obviously, the `get_header` function does not exist and I can't find a way to access already set headers.

Is that even possible?

**EDIT after comments:**

`headers_sent` is not the function I am looking for. This functions checks if the headers have already been sent to the client.

Comment: [getallheaders()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.getallheaders.php) ?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.headers-sent.php - first Google result btw. for your question title verbatim ...

Comment: @CD001 `getallheaders` gets request headers I think, and @CBroe I think that the `headers_sent` function is a boolean that says if the headers have already been sent to the client

Comment: I don't want to check if the headers have already been sent, I want to check the value of a pending header to be sent..

Comment: ... but if it's a pending header to be send, how do you expect to check it if it's not been sent yet?

Comment: I don't want to check if it has been sent, I want to check the value that has been assigned to this header

Comment: What about http://php.net/manual/en/function.headers-list.php

Comment: That seems better @AlonEitan, thank you, you can make it a response, I will mark it as resolved

Comment: I voted to reopen, since it's obviously not a duplicate

Comment: @AlonEitan ... at least not a duplicate of *that* question, I bet if someone was to rummage enough it'll be here, somewhere ;) Good catch on the OP wanting the **response** headers.

Comment: Thank you, I see the obviousness of the question here, but I could not find any result in google, maybe I should have had to browse on the PHP doc directly

Comment: There is probably a different duplicate - If you wish you can delete this question and then we can pretend like this never happened  ;)

Comment: To be honest, there are questions about the `headers_list` function, that are relative to the behaviour of the function in itself, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31555392/php-headers-list-is-not-showing-all-headers https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17646229/get-php-content-type-from-header or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4475345/unsorted-array-headers-list-make-keys-for-array but none of them respond to the exact same question. Anyways, the community will decide to reopen or not. But I think @AlonEitan deserves his 25 points for that as he responded to the question.

Comment: That's totally fine by me @Hammerbot, I'm not doing this for the reputation :)

Comment: headers_sent() method in php you can use